# In Jenkins how to trigger another build job based on the build parameter passed to current build job?

Tags: jenkins, build, hudson

I have build jobs like `a-build`, `a-deploy`. `b-build`, `b-deploy`.

`*-deploy` are downstream job for `*-build` jobs. So they look like,

```
a-build
|
+-a-deploy


b-build
|
+-b-deploy
```

Now I have another job `X-build`. It accepts `a-build`, `b-build` etc as a parameter.  So I if I run `X-build` with `a-build` as parameter it should complete with a post build action that triggers `a-deploy`. How can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this quite easily if you receive the job name in a parameter.
You can then use "Call/Trigger Builds on Other Projects" step, and use the Parameter you receive in the job name:

[image: Jenkins]

If the step is not available to you via Post Build menu, you can get to it via "Execute set of scripts" post-build step.
[image: Jenkins]